# What was her name?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I had a match with a stunning girl on tinder yesterday, I was overjoyed but then I found out that she had the most bizarre name. What was more odd was what she wrote on her profile:

Welcome gentlemen to my tutorial on how to play me the right way: At the beginning of my life, I was never quite a creature with a painful and deadly bite. After that, I was never quite in possession of politeness either. With all that said, if you now break me it will be hell on earth for you. All in all, I might sound like a fearsome gal but just like you all I need is a few kisses in the right places to win me.

However, that was not where it ended, the strangest thing of all was how oddly her name matched her profile. As if it were a riddle for it. Therefore I thought it was a catfish and so I decided to ignore it. Admittedly, I was a little sad but then I saw that it had great potential for a good puzzle. So my question is...

What was her name?

Hints:

> Her name is more than one word.

> There is a game here.

> Look at the last sentence of her profile to start.

A big hint:

> One could say that she included her middle name on it.

A very big hint:

> The number 3 is crucial to this puzzle in more ways than one.

Comment: Just to add this is not a true story.

Comment: Also I just changed in possession to lacking.

Comment: I realised a mistake I am switching back sorry

Comment: There is a 50 bounty to anyone who can provide the correct reasons for the answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps your fearsome gal is

> Tic Tac Toe.

At the start, it’s a clean board, so there’s no hint of pain.

As the game progresses, courtesy is strained as each player frustrates the other in order to keep things going.

In the movie

> War Games,

global catastrophe was averted because this game was unable to be broken.

Addressing the clues:

- the name has 3 words,
- there is indeed a game here,
- the traditional markings used in the game also correspond to the text-symbolic encodings of kisses,
- the middle name was *tac*fully included, and
- there are 3 lots of possible spaces in each cardinal direction.

Comment: *"the name has 3 words"* Also each word has three letters. +1 from me.

Comment: You got the right answer!!

Comment: But you need to make the clues fit... I will give you the green check, someone needs to explain how this relates to the clues.

Comment: Your reasons are not correct.

Comment: @Deepthinker101 Thanks! Have I missed all the clues, or are there specific ones you’d like me to redo?

Comment: El guest has all the correct reasons... I want to give you the answer tick and him the bounty but I can't do it.

Comment: @Deepthinker101 I see that El-guest has provided the reasoning you were after. Unless you prefer me to edit, I’ll leave my answer as is, so that I don’t leave El-guest’s answer hanging.

Comment: @Deepthinker101 Oops, our messages crossed in the aether. I’ve left a link on El-guests’s comment thread regarding separate bounty / green tick assignment.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to say her name is

> Billie Yards

General Reasoning

> The main profile text seems to contain several things which hint at the cue sports (snooker/pool/billiards) and billiards is the one which most sounds like a person's name.

Welcome gentlemen to my tutorial on how to play me the right way:

> Suggestive that what we are looking for is a game (also explicitly suggested in the hints)

At the beginning of my life, I was never quite a creature with a painful and deadly bite.

> I think this may be referring to the **spider** rest which is a type of rest used in cue sports but rarely (if ever) at the start of the game.

After that, I was never quite lacking in politeness either.

> In the cue sports, missed shots are called **fouls**. Most players will encounter fouls during a game which sounds like they are not being polite

With all that said, if you now break me it will be hell on earth for you.

> The shot at the start of a game to separate the balls is called a **break**. Also, a sequence of consecutively potted balls constitutes a **break**. Not completely sure about the *hell on earth* bit.

All in all, I might sound like a fearsome gal but just like you all I need is a few kisses in the right places to win me.

> In the cue sports, a slight touch of a ball against another ball is known as a **kiss** and a few of these made during a game is usually quite helpful.

Comment: A very nice try but not the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I’m going to respond with more of the explanation, as I believe @Lawrence’s answer has already been identified as correct:

Welcome gentlemen to my tutorial on how to play me the right way:

At the beginning of my life, I was never quite a creature with a painful and deadly bite.

> A creature with a painful and deadly bite is a TICK (think tick bites, Lyme disease, etc.) She *never quite* was a TICK, so removing the last letter clues TIC as the first word.

After that, I was never quite in possession of politeness either.

> Being in possession of politeness is the definition of having TACT. She *never quite* had TACT, so removing the last letter clues TAC as the second word.

With all that said, if you now break me it will be hell on earth for you.

> Lastly, what feels like hell on earth? For one, breaking your TOE does! This clues TOE as the final word.

All in all, I might sound like a fearsome gal but just like you all I need is a few kisses in the right places to win me.

> Hugs and kisses in text slang are clued as XOXO (X’s and O’s). If you put the X’s (or O’s) in the right places (ie. a line of three of them in a row) you can win at TIC-TAC-TOE!

Comment: Congratulations.

Comment: How do I award you the bounty but not the answer.

Comment: @Deepthinker101 Bounties can be awarded independently of green ticks. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) is more info.

Comment: Ok just wait for a day...

Answer (score -2):

Her name will be like:

```
Bizarre Fearsome gal
```

Most of the time the words are from the riddle only.. and according to the hint "The number 3 is crucial to this puzzle" the name has 3 words.

Comment: You should be able to explain the clues given in the riddle. This answer does not do that.